# How to Include_tasks with relative path?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to Include a file which contains tasks, but it fails:

> ERROR! Unable to retrieve file contents Could not find or access
> '/roles/k8s/tasks/Get_volumes.yaml' on the Ansible Controller. If you
> are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the
> remote_src option

Below is my ansible script. As I am going to test only a few tasks, I have included the tasks file which is inside the roles folder. I am not sure if it fails because of the roles folder.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    local_kubectl: kubectl
    local_array_api_url: https://Mystoragearray:5392/v1
    array_username: admin
    array_password: admin

  tasks: 
    #- import_tasks: /roles/k8s/tasks/GetVolume_token.yaml
    - include_tasks: /roles/k8s/tasks/Get_volumes.yaml
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: ***How to include_tasks with relative path?***

A: Place the file relative to the playbook base directory [*playbook_dir*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html?highlight=playbook_dir). For example

```yaml
    - include_tasks: Get_volumes.yaml
```

is the same as

```yaml
    - include_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/Get_volumes.yaml"
```

If the directory */roles* is configured in [*DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-roles-path) then [*include_role*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role) might be a better option

```yaml
    - include_role:
        name: k8s
        tasks_from: Get_volumes.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the path again. is path "/roles/k8s/tasks/Get_volumes.yaml" correct?  it should be something like "roles/k8s/tasks/Get_volumes.yaml". 
if path is correct ( seems to be starting from root directory "/"), please provide necessary permission to the ansible user.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a relative path. You specified a path which starts with `/`, which is the definition of an absolute path.

In this/your case: do not specify a path at all, only the file name, as ansible will pick it up from its search path.

On my system, it got picked up from the directory where the executed playbook was residing, and/or from the `tasks` subdir of a role which was referenced.

Read the (complicated) [ansible search path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbook_pathing.html) rules...